# Toggle arrow using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to toggle an arrow using React. found some examples online, but still not able to make it work.

this is what I have so far:

```js
class Footer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false,
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({
      active: !currentState
    })
  }
  

render() {
    return (
        <footer className="footer">
          <section className="container">
            <a className="visible-xs" role="button">
                       Social
              <i onClick={this.handleClick} className={this.state.active ? "fa fa-chevron-up" : "fa fa-chevron-down"} aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </a>
          </section>
         </footer>
    )
  }
}
         
module.exports = Footer;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you forgot to bind the `this.handleClick` method, use this line in constructor: `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `handleClick` function is not being called with the expected scope.

From the [React doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html):

> You have to be careful about the meaning of *this* in JSX callbacks. In
>   JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
>   bind *this.handleClick* and pass it to *onClick*, *this* will be *undefined*
>   when the function is actually called.

Add this line of code at the end of your constructor:

```
// This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ES7 you can use helpful syntax to automatically bind your methods to your class, and make it more legible:

```
class Footer extends React.Component {  
  state = { active: false }

  handleClick = () => {
    const { currentState } = this.state;
    this.setState({ active: !currentState });
  }

  render() {
    const { active } = this.state;
    return (
      <footer className="footer">
        <section className="container">
          <a className="visible-xs" role="button">
            Social
            <i onClick={this.handleClick} className={active ? "fa fa-chevron-up" : "fa fa-chevron-down"} aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
        </section>
      </footer>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = Footer;
```